# sqlite query to get instances were no items returned on join

Tags: sqlite

I am querying the static backend db for a game I play (trying to keep up on my coding), and I am having an issue getting the full results that I want.

So the query that I have so far is:

```
select ms.security, mc.constellationName, mr.regionName, ms.solarSystemName, count(it.typename) as NumberOfBelts
from mapSolarSystems as ms
    join mapConstellations as mc on ms.constellationID == mc.constellationID
    join mapRegions as mr on ms.regionID == mr.regionID
    join invItems as ii on ii.locationID = ms.solarSystemID
    join invTypes as it on it.typeID == ii.typeID
where it.groupID = 9
group by  solarSystemName
```

the problem comes when there are no rows where it.groupID == 9.  What I need is for the count to return 0 and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this to work.

I tried doing left outer join on the final join statement, but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last join to a `left` join and set the condition in the `on` clause istead of the `where` clause:

```
select ms.security, mc.constellationName, mr.regionName, ms.solarSystemName, count(it.typename) as NumberOfBelts
from mapSolarSystems as ms
    join mapConstellations as mc on ms.constellationID = mc.constellationID
    join mapRegions as mr on ms.regionID = mr.regionID
    join invItems as ii on ii.locationID = ms.solarSystemID
    left join invTypes as it on it.typeID = ii.typeID and it.groupID = 9
group by  solarSystemName
```